# Adding custom language culture in Azure

Tags: azure, paas

I am trying to add/register custom language culture in Azure, can anyone share your thoughts on the same?.
There is a  similar article on the same subject- but it looks old(based on startup tasks) and I believe there should be a  way to add the culture in Azure.

Another link as ref-
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/07/custom-cultures-coming-soon-to-azure-app-service/

Do we have a working example, and how it will be deployed to Azure?

Thanks in advance.
-Ankit

Comment: Could you summarize your query better? so when you say **add culture in Azure**, which azure offering are you using to host your application? Is it a **Azure VM, Azure Cloud Service** or **Azure App Service**?

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday- I am trying to add custom culture in Azure App Service.